# PHP Decryption Function Does Not Work In Some Situations

Tags: php, encryption

I use the following php functions to perform encryption and decryption.  In my application, I have one admin user page which performs CRUD activities.  Sensitive data are encrypted before database update and decrypted before rendered on screen.  Both encryption and decryption work fine. However in another page which only reads record from database and the same decryption function always return blank.

These function are located in one single php file.  To ensure the same function is called from both pages, I purposely changed `base64_decode` to a bad name and both calling page errored out.

Does anyone have a clue under what situation would this decryption function works in one page and doesn't work in another page?

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$key = '2780e3ddec78d5da74e171aba36cd916';

function encryptthis($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}
function decryptthis($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2),2,null);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}
?>
```

I simplified the calling programs but they look pretty muck like below:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/init.php';
$Sys = new Sys();
$sysRow = $Sys -> sys_Get();  // use PDO to get record from database
$pwd = decryptthis($sysRow['password'], $key);
?>
```

Edited:
I also created the following to test.  How comes the encrypted data always change every time I run it?

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/init.php';
$a = encryptthis('TESTING DATE', 'key');
echo $a;
echo "<br>";
$b = decryptthis($a, 'key');
echo $b;
?>
```

Edited:
The following shows it returns blank. The first parameter is the encrypted value in database.  I just hardcoded here to show it returned blank.

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/init.php';
$a = decryptthis('TEo5djR2TmpFd3VPaU9ZZjZRSTg5SW81OFZPK3llejlFczljdU1tMFVxQ0FySDZNKy9nUThxQS9ucGRtZ0FVUTo6Ooau42Z/kvO2EFot64nbRA==', $key);
echo $a;
?>
```

but in another page which allows user to add and change it returns d9cB4e50e8324Ae19b5dCb1676C83FCa (that's actual value before encryption).

Comment: need to show more code, like how you're selecting the rows, the table structure and values and how your calling the funcs and passing values and the key etc

Comment: _How comes the encrypted data always change every time I run it?_: This is because a random IV is used for each encryption (which is correct, since the non-deterministic ciphertext is a security feature). Maybe you use different keys for encryption and decryption? You should post an example for which decryption fails (plaintext, ciphertext, key).

Comment: Your example key seems wrong. It looks like it's hex-encoded. If there are 32 hexits then the decoded key has 128 bit. If you treat it as base64 instead (which you do), you get a 192 bit key, but then you want to use AES-256 which needs a 256 bit key. So you actually have to generate a 256 bit key and encode it to base64 to use it. When you do that it will be 44 characters long.

Comment: Topaco: Is the 2nd parameter ($key) the key?  In my 3rd snippet, I purposely hardcoded to 'key' but result changes every time.

Comment: Artjom B: I'm not sure which part should be corrected to make it right as per your comments.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in his line

```
array_pad(explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2),2,null);
```

Being `null` at the end means if the array doesn't return the expected length (in this case 2) then will return `null`

I think you might need to update your question showing the raw data to help you out better; but what I feel is happening (without knowing the raw data) is the data being passed doesn't contain `::`. One reason could be the `$sysRow['password']` is not returning the raw data or extra data instead

Comment: Original edited to show the raw data and the scenario it returns blank.  But in the other page (allow user to add/change) it returns the correct raw data.

Comment: It seems your problem is fetching the data from PDO. Try the following before going further: `$sysRow = $Sys -> sys_Get();  echo 'returned: '.$sysRow['password'];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did assume PDO is not returning the encrypted properly and created the last snippet to debug on which I hardcoded the 1st parameter with the value I directly copied from MySQL workbench but the result is still blank.

Comment: Well, I just decoded the Base64 `TEo5djR2TmpFd3VPaU9ZZjZRSTg5SW81OFZPK3llejlFczljdU1tMFVxQ0FySDZNKy9nUThxQS9ucGRtZ0FVUTo6Ooau42Z/kvO2EFot64nbRA==` is showing `:::` instead of `::` so that could be another error on your decrypt code

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what happened.  I have two init.php file in different folder and the keys are different.

Sorry for false alarm.